# search entire column for partial string or characters matches and display result on another column

Tags: excel

Need some help writing a macro that is capable of searching an entire column of alpha-numeric values that contains partial matches and display the result on the column beside it.

In simpler terms, I need it to work like "Find Duplicates" in conditional formatting but the curve ball here is that the comparison is partial text instead of the entire cell value. Hope I'm making sense.

[image: sample output]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you show us what you have tried so far, and where you have gotten stuck with this? Not showing any effort on your part will most likely [get you downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and you will be unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: _"Need some help writing a macro"_ So, did you start, and you need help with your current code? If so, where is it?

Comment: Your example is rather inconsistent for matching up the results. Rows 4 and 6 both have melon, 2 and 6 both have Endive, and B3 should probably have both Blackberries and Boysenberries, among other things

Comment: The rules and the example need to be more clearly defined after you make an attempt

Comment: It seems you had word-wrapping turned off when you did the screenshot. In looking for duplicates, are you looking at each individual word?  Or each line?  If line, you will need Excel 2016 or later; for each word, you will need VBA or Power Query.

Comment: In your list, the following are duplicated: `BelgianEndive | Blackberries | Boysenberries | Celery | Chayote`  What is the logic behind what you have listed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown what you have tried before asking, I won't give you a complete code, but follow this direction and you would be able to make it.

- Define a function to extract the words from a cell and return a list.
- Define another function to check out the non matching members and return it.
- Make the main function to get two range object (cells) and then send them too function 1 and two.

Your code should be something like this:

```vb
private function f1(r as range)
' will return the array of words identified from the capital character
end function
private function f2(l1 as string[],l2 as string[])
'will take two lists and return non dublicate members like you need.
end function
public function find_unique(r1 as range,r2 as range)
' will take those cells and call f1 to get lists then f2 to get the unique members
end function
```